# > Could not get unknown property 'release' for SigningConfig container of type org.gradle.api.internal.FactoryNamedDomainObjectContainer

Tags: flutter

I am writing to complain about a problem that I am having with the Flutter plugin on Stack Overflow. I am trying to build a Flutter project, but I am getting the error message "Could not find method buildTypes() for arguments [build_2oalreweyj2so7xyy5tza4f8c$_run_closure3@25e5467e] on project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project."

I have tried to follow the instructions on the Stack Overflow documentation, but I am still getting the error. I have also tried to search for solutions on the forum, but I have not found anything that has worked.

I am hoping that you can help me to resolve this issue. I am a beginner with Flutter, and I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Thank you for your time and attention to this matter.

My message ereur is
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\Users\imade\Downloads\Newsfreak_v2.0.4\Newsfreak v2.0.4\main_files\source\wordpress_app\android\app\build.gradle' line: 55
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> Could not get unknown property 'release' for SigningConfig container of type org.gradle.api.internal.FactoryNamedDomainObjectContainer.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                         2,010ms
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
Process finished with exit code 1

My probleme in my github
https://github.com/ImadPro69/wordpress_app/tree/a45fece5ede10b9b01aa832fe907067098b09a5b

I have tried to follow the instructions on the Stack Overflow documentation, but I am still getting the error. I have also tried to search for solutions on the forum, but I have not found anything that has worked.

I am hoping that you can help me to resolve this issue. I am a beginner with Flutter, and I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Thank you for your time and attention to this matter.

My message ereur is
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\Users\imade\Downloads\Newsfreak_v2.0.4\Newsfreak v2.0.4\main_files\source\wordpress_app\android\app\build.gradle' line: 55
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> Could not get unknown property 'release' for SigningConfig container of type org.gradle.api.internal.FactoryNamedDomainObjectContainer.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                         2,010ms
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
Process finished with exit code 1

My probleme in my github
https://github.com/ImadPro69/wordpress_app/tree/a45fece5ede10b9b01aa832fe907067098b09a5b

Answer (score 1):

try to execute the command, it helped me: flutter clean